# Installation Blend4web 2.76

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, installation

I wanted to know, how I can install blend4web in version 2.76?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably best asked at the specified product user forum or website, or follow the instructions of the creator, since it doesn't seem like a Blender specific question.

Try following [these instructions](https://www.blend4web.com/doc/en/first_steps.html#index-1) from the addon author documentation

Answer (score 1):

1. Open Blender.
2. Open the User Preferences panel **File > User Preferences....**
3. Open the **File** tab.
4. Set the path to the SDK directory in the **Scripts** field.
5. Click the **Save User Settings** button.
6. Restart Blender.
7. Once again, open the **User Preferences** panel **File > User Preferences....**
8. Open the **Add-ons** tab.
9. Enable the Blend4Web add-on.
10. Click the **Save User Settings** button.

To verify it worked:

In the **File > Export** menu, the **Blend4Web (.json)** and **Blend4Web (.html)** options should appear.